# Error 500 with Google AppEngine, and class java.net

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a problem with gae. I have an application http://www.similarityface.appspot.com/query. I am trying through a program in java to communicate with this application to perform query, via the POST method. The problem that is generating 500 error.
The code is below, could someone help me telling what I'm doing wrong.

```
public class Vetores_Facebook {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
        final String server = "https://www.similarityface.appspot.com/query";
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(server);

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Vetores_Facebook.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    HttpURLConnection urlConn = null;
    try {
        // URL connection channel.
        urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Vetores_Facebook.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


    urlConn.setDoOutput (true);

    // No caching, we want the real thing.
    urlConn.setUseCaches (false);

    try {    

        urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    } catch (ProtocolException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Vetores_Facebook.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    try {

        urlConn.connect();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Vetores_Facebook.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    String message = URLEncoder.encode("get_object(\"me\", metadata=1)", "UTF-8");
    try (OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConn.getOutputStream())) {
        writer.write(message);
        writer.close();

    }



     if (urlConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
         System.out.println("ok");
        }
     else{
            int x = urlConn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("error "+x);

     }
 }
}
```

Comment: You are using POST, so you should be sending some data, right?

Comment: Sure, in the case i am sending the argument "get_object(\"me\", metadata=1)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {

    urlConn.connect();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Vetores_Facebook.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

String message = URLEncoder.encode("get_object(\"me\", metadata=1)", "UTF-8");
try (OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConn.getOutputStream())) {
    writer.write(message);
    writer.close();

}
```

The problem is you are calling urlConn.connect(); which seems to flush any output buffers you may have and prepares the connection to get an input stream. Trying to write to open an output stream after this will cause an exception.

Use the example given here for the correct way to do this: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/usingjavanet#Using_HttpURLConnection

Comment: Not giving error over this part the program ends:
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter (urlConn.getOutputStream (), which can be?